# Clone git bare repository behind private vpn

Tags: git, putty, amazon-web-services

I'm working on a basic project under an aws network.
The project use a tipical vpn with a public subnet with an elb that forward traffic to a private subnet where the code resides.

I used to work on the private subnet with a tunnel launched throught putty and then passing files with filezilla. The process works fine.

Now, I want to go a step further and start using git as version controller of my project, I set up an initial repository and a bare repository inside the private subnet.

Then in my local desktop I have to clone the bare repository and start working on the project and push changes to the remote one.

With my tunnel on, I try with:

```
git clone ssh://private_ip/path/to/bare/repo.git repo
```

but the bash say:

```
connect to host private_ip port 22: connection timed out please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

I try with a combination of access but none seems to work:

```
git clone ssh://user@public_ip:22/private_ip/path/to/bare/repo.git repo //permission denied (publickey)

git clone ssh://user@private_ip/path/to/bare/repo.git repo //connection timed out
```

am I missing something? What the correct url to connect to the private subnet under a tunnel? Is there a better way to manage the vcs?

Thank you

Comment: Does your user have ssh access to your repo?

Comment: Hi, I can connect to the bastion (nat) on the public layer and from there I can ssh user@private_id and access the server. I can also connect through the tunnel with filezilla.

Comment: using the same username?

Comment: yess, but when I open git bash and try to ssh to clone a bare repo I can't.

Comment: I set up another tunnel, user@public_ip:22 L3333 private_ip:22 with (allow agent forwarding). I add my private key to pageant. I launch the tunnel session. I open git bash. I want to connect to the repo in private_ip and the command I have to write is ..?

Answer (score 0):

If you are listening on `port 3333` and forwarding to `private_ip:22`, you need to use your `localhost` with the port you are listening on:

`git clone ssh://user@localhost:3333/path/to/bare/repo.git repo`

PS: Make sure your user has SSH access to the `private_ip` host

Comment: I run the command and the reply is "user@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).". I'm sure user can access private_ip because I work on remote server daily. even filezilla can easily login through the tunnel

Comment: @Mindexperiment Well “Permission denied” means the connection did indeed reach the SSH server—for which you did not supply the required credentials.

Comment: ok , good news! But, I'm using the default ec2-user credentials, I don't think I have others credentials

Comment: As a test, did you try to ssh directly to localhost port 3333?

Comment: I solve the problem by setting my public key as the authorized_keys on the private server.

Comment: So the key/user was not the same you used for ssh and git?